# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on webpack setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am playing around webpack and react.

Basically, I have the two files `utils.js` and `app.js` file sitting under my `src` folder.

Here's the content of my `utils.js` file:

```
const square = (x) => x * x;

export { square };
```

Here's my `app.js` file:

```
import { square } from './utils.js';

console.log('i Hello from app.js here!');

console.log(square(4));
```

When I run my app via `yarn run build` it gave me this error:

```
app.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app.js:3
```

I checked out my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

I think I am doing good. What's wrong with my code? What does require even means?

Comment: looks all good, what's the "build" command looks like in the package.json?

Comment: ` <script src="/bundle.js"></script>` I found the culprit. It supposed to be the bundle.js file not script.js file sitting on my index.html file under public folder.

Comment: It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a CommonJS module from within your browser. This will not work.
How are you using them? When you write import ... from ... in ES6 Babel will transpile these calls to a module definition called CommonJS and since CommonJS isn't around in the browser you'll get an undefined error from require().
If you want to use CommonJS modules in your code base you need to first bundle them with either Browserify or webpack. The two tools will transform your require calls to some glue magic that you can use within the browser.

Comment: ` <script src="/bundle.js"></script>` I found the culprit. It supposed to be the `bundle.js` file not `script.js` file sitting on my index.html file under public folder.

Comment: @JoanBuan If my answer is helpful, please upvote my answer. Thanks alot.